# Using uglifyjs on M1 Pro with ZSH throws error

Tags: zsh, apple-m1

If I execute the following in terminal on my Macbook M1 Pro 2021 with ZSH

```
uglifyjs js/script.js --compress --mangle --output js/script.min.js -m reserved=['$','require','exports']
```

I get this error

```
zsh: no matches found: reserved=[$,require,exports]
```

But If I switch to bash then it's fine, can anyone help on this to get it fixed on ZSH?

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes:

```
uglifyjs js/script.js --compress --mangle --output js/script.min.js \
-m "reserved=['$','require','exports']"
```

In both `bash` and `zsh`, square brackets are used for file globbing. The shell is attempting to find files that match the pattern `reserved=[<one of these characters>]`

In `zsh`, if there are no matches, you get an error. In `bash` if there are no matches, the shell *silently* includes the original pattern.

Which means in `bash`, you also want to use quotes to prevent file globbing. Otherwise, something like this can happen:

```
bash> echo reserved=['$','require','exports']
reserved=[$,require,exports]
bash> touch 'reserved=r'
bash> echo reserved=['$','require','exports']
reserved=r
```